# How do I center a div below a centered div?

Tags: css

I essentially have 3 main divs: outer div, first div, and second div.

```
<div class = "outer">
    <div class = "first">

    </div>

    <div class = "second">

    </div>
</div>
```

The only CSS that I am currently applying is to the first div:

```
.first {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    min-height: 14em;
    width: 46%;
    top: 5em;
}
```

Because initially I was only focusing on centering the first div. I wasn't thinking ahead and planning to create the second div.

Anyway, the second div is currently displaying to the top left of the first div and I want it to display beneath the first div while being horizontally centered but I don't know to do that. I have tried adding a clear: both to the second div in the hopes of it "clearing" the first div so that it can move below it but that didn't work.

Comment: why are you using `position: fixed`? Other elements will not know where `.first` is on the page as long as it's `fixed`, so they won't flow around it unless `.first` has a defined height and you position the other elements around it manually.

Comment: You can't "clear" anything that's `position: fixed`, that actually doesn't make any sense. It's essentially position absolute anchored to the viewport (instead of anchoring to it's nearest `position: relative` parent). Here's a pretty good write up on the `position` property - https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think I was using it incorrectly (I initially thought that using position:fixed would make the div able to accommodate to different screen sizes or something). I removed it now! The first div still remains centered and the second div is now bottom left of the first div.

Comment: is this what you're going for? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gWEObg the trick to horizontally centering something is to give it a `width` and use `margin-left/margin-right: auto` like you did with `.first`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have a "position:fixed" on the first div. If for some reason you do need the divs to be fixed you can add it to the outermost "outer" div. I did a quick pen in codepen and put the working code below.

```
.outer{

position:fixed;
width:100%;
}

.first {
margin:auto;
min-height: 14em;
width: 46%;
top: 5em;
}

.second{
 width:46%;
 height:50px;
 margin:auto;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
.first {
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;margin-top:0.3em;
        min-height: 14em;
        width: 46%;
        background: red;
    }
    .second{margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        min-height: 14em;margin-top:0.3em;
        width: 46%;background: blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't quite clear whether you are meaning to use `position: fixed`, but I will operate under the assumption that you are.

Using flexbox:

HTML

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="first">
  </div>
  <div class="second">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.first, .second {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50vh;
}

.first {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: blue;
}

.second {
  margin-top: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/hT9vP/)